# Executing the route request for Bing Maps API with C#

Tags: c#, rest, bing-api

I am working with BingMapsRESTToolkit trying to get route. It works fine with simple request without departure, but when I add `TimeType = RouteTimeType.Departure` and `DateTime = new DateTime(637925211000000000)` to the request it returns exception:

`Exception: There was an issue downloading and serializing the results. Results Download URL: https://routematrixpremium.blob.core.windows.net/finalresults/a2782565-6849-4df1-9521-18647aa87665 There was an error deserializing the object of type BingMapsRESTToolkit.DistanceMatrix. Encountered unexpected character 'ï'.`

I checked the response manually with URL in the browser but I didn't find this character and everything seems to be ok.

```
public List<Route> responseList;
static string key = "mykey";

private async void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            responseList = new List<Route>();
            var request = new RouteRequest()
            {
                Waypoints = new List<SimpleWaypoint>() {
                    new SimpleWaypoint(39.951916, -75.150118),
                    new SimpleWaypoint(40.745702, -73.847184)
                },
                WaypointOptimization = BingMapsRESTToolkit.Extensions.TspOptimizationType.TravelDistance,
                RouteOptions = new RouteOptions()
                {
                    TravelMode = TravelModeType.Driving,
                    TimeType = RouteTimeType.Departure,
                    //DateTime = new DateTime(2022, 07, 04, 8, 45, 0)
                    DateTime = new DateTime(637925211000000000)
                },
                BingMapsKey = key
            };

            var response = await request.Execute();//exception!

            if (response != null &&
                response.ResourceSets != null &&
                response.ResourceSets.Length > 0 &&
                response.ResourceSets[0].Resources != null &&
                response.ResourceSets[0].Resources.Length > 0)
            {
                responseList.Add(response.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as BingMapsRESTToolkit.Route);

                //Do something with the result.
                richTextBox1.Text += "TravelDistance: " + responseList[0].RouteLegs[0].TravelDistance + Environment.NewLine;
                richTextBox1.Text += "TravelDuration: " + responseList[0].RouteLegs[0].TravelDuration + Environment.NewLine;
            }
```

Comment: Seems to be unfixable. In this case I handle with the XML response manualy and try to find everything there by myself. But in other cases I continue to work with BingMapsRESTToolkit.